# What files should be code-signed with an EV certificate

Tags: certificate, code-signing, authenticode

I'm currently looking at how my company signs our files.  Currently we use an EV 
certificate to sign almost every file in our installer, including the installer.  I'm new to this code signing stuff so I may get somethings wrong.

Unfortunately signing with an EV cert makes our CI system more complicated and has introduced the occasional failure. The dependencies on the EV cert is a bottleneck may prevent our system from scaling. We still want to sign all our files, the question is do we need to sign all the files with an EV cert?

Is it a bad idea EV and OV certificates, for example use an OV certificate on the installed files, but EV for the installer and Iso?

What about certificate rollover, will that be a problem if we start signing with an OV cert?

Any other problems that may occur when switching from an EV to an OV cert for the installed files?

Most of what I've found compares the two types but doesn't talk about when one should be used over another, when an EV really should be used over an OV, or if it's ok to use an OV cert.